# PHP How get words from string and store them in a simple array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

Please I have this string :

```
$s = "Cannes (06150-06400), Limoges (87000-87100-87280), 06000, Paris";
```

I want to store only **words** in an array, so I tried this :

```
$villes = explode(',', preg_replace('#\(([0-9\-]*)\)#', '', $s));
```

But in result I get this array :

```
array(4) {
          [0]=>
             string(7) "Cannes "
          [1]=>
             string(9) " Limoges "
          [2]=>
             string(7) "  06000" // This shouldn't be displayed in the array
          [3]=>
             string(6) " Paris"
         }
```

Please how could I modify the regex to get it work as I wish. Thanks.

Comment: what about `str_word_count($string, 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$arr = preg_split('/\s*\(?[\d\-\s]*\)?\s*,\s*/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(6) "Cannes"
  [1] =>
  string(7) "Limoges"
  [2] =>
  string(5) "Paris"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<?php
$s = "Cannes (06150-06400), Limoges (87000-87100-87280), 06000, Paris";
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]+/", $s, $villes);
var_dump($villes[0]);
?>
```

For single word names.
Var dump:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Cannes"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Limoges"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Paris"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match( '/[a-zA-Z\-\']+/', $s, $words );
var_dump( $words[0] );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array for result.

```
$arr=explode(' ' , $s);
print_r($arr);
```